# How to get all the tags (with content) under a certain class with BeautifulSoup?

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup, html-parsing

I have a class in my soup element that is the description of a unit.

```
<div class="ats-description">
 <p>Here is a paragraph</p>
 <div>inner div</div>
 <div>Another div</div>
 <ul>
    <li>Item1</li>
    <li>Item2</li>
    <li>Item3</li>
 </ul>
</div>
```

I can easily grab this part with `soup.select(".ats-description")[0]`.
Now I want to remove `<div class="ats-description">`, only to keep all the inner tags (to retain text structure). How to do it?

`soup.select(".ats-description")[0].getText()` gives me all the texts within, like this:

```
'\nHere is a paragraph\ninner div\nAnother div\n\nItem1\nItem2\nItem3\n\n\n'
```

But removes all the inner tags, so it's just unstructured text. I want to keep the tags as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to get innerHTML, use method `.decode_contents()`

```
innerHTML = soup.select_one('.ats-description').decode_contents()
print(innerHTML)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, match by tag in list in `soup.find_all()`

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html="""<div class="ats-description">
 <p>Here is a paragraph</p>
 <div>inner div</div>
 <div>Another div</div>
 <ul>
    <li>Item1</li>
    <li>Item2</li>
    <li>Item3</li>
 </ul>
</div>"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
print(soup.select_one("div.ats-description").find_all(['p','div','ul']))
```

Comment: I don't know what will be inside this. So, I can't hardcode all the tags as u do. It might or might not work.